# Problem in creating a shortcode form custom post type slider

Tags: shortcode

I am trying to build a shortcode of my custom slider. The following is my code :

```
add_shortcode('teresa_stories_courage_slider', 'teresa_stories_courage_slider_shortcodes');
function teresa_stories_courage_slider_shortcodes( $atts, $content = null){

                           $return_content = '';
                           $return_content .= '<div class="featured-block clearfix">';
                          $return_content .= '<div id="courage" class="flexslider">';

                         $return_content .= '<ul class="slides">';


                           global $posts;

                           $courage_args = array(
                              'post_type' => 'stories_courage',
                              'posts_per_page' => '-1',
                              'order' => 'ASC'


                           );

                           $the_courage_query = new WP_Query( $courage_args );
                           if( $the_courage_query -> have_posts()) : while( $the_courage_query -> have_posts() ) : $the_courage_query ->the_post(); 



                          $return_content .= '<li>';
                           $return_content .= '<div class="courage-wrapper">';

                        $return_content .= '<div class="img-box">';
                           $return_content .=' <a href=" '. the_permalink() . '" rel="bookmark">'; 
                             if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
                             $return_content .= the_post_thumbnail( 'courage_image' );
                             }else{

                             $return_content .= '<img src="' . IMAGE_PATH . 'blank-img-slider.jpg ">' ;
                             }
                             $return_content .= '</a>';
                             $return_content .=' </div>';



                          $return_content .=' <div class="courage-content">';
                           $return_content .=  substr( strip_tags( the_content() ), 0, 77); 

                           $return_content .='<span class="pull-right courage-more">';
                           $return_content .= '<a rel="bookmark" href="'. the_permalink(). '">';
                           $return_content .= '<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right "></i>';
                           $return_content .= '</a>';
                           $return_content .= '</span>';

                           $return_content .='</div>';
                           $return_content .='</div>'; 
                           $return_content .= '</li>';

                           endwhile;
                          endif; 



                          $return_content .='</ul>';

                          $return_content .='</div>';
                          $return_content .='</div>';
                          wp_reset_query();
                          return $return_content;



    }
```

But in the front end the entire code is breaking and looking like this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BZdw.png
Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're using template functions that echo their value in variable assignment, you need to use the equivalent `get_` functions that return their value.

Comment: Yes @Milo you are right. I was doing the mistake. It is now solved.Thanks for your help